# get path from kml geoxml3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geoxml3, geoxml

I am working with google maps and using geoxml3 to parse my kml string and its showing on Google maps , now I want to get lines info like number of lines in kml string  and its  location can i get the info of lines drawn by parsed kml string?

**html**

```
<div id="map" style="height: 720px"></div>
```

app.ts

```
function parseKml() {

    var myParser = new geoXML3.parser({map: map});
    myParser.parseKmlString(kmlString);


  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can get description related to kml string/file by :

```
myParser.docs[0].placemarks[0]
myParser.docs[0].placemarks[1]
myParser.docs[0].placemarks[2]
```

use it accordingly as I have three lines

Answer (score 1):

you can also get path from kml like this :

```js
var myParser = new geoXML3.parser({
    map: map, //your map
    afterParse: function(doc) { // callback after parse
        for (var i = 0; i < doc[0].placemarks.length; i++) {                
            console.log(doc[0].placemarks[i].LineString[0].coordinates) //for coordinates - doc[0].placemarks[i] get more info
        }
    }
});
myParser.parse('http://googlemaps.github.io/js-v2-samples/ggeoxml/cta.kml');
```

for example